# Awkward implementation of add function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am struggling to see why this:

```
addItem = item => {
    this.setState({ grudges: [grudge, ...this.state.grudges] });
}
```

rather awkward implementation exists. Wouldn't

```
this.state.grudges.push(grudge)
```

suffice?

Comment: This is **not** [tag:java]. Please don't add tags for languages you don't know.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wouldn't be suffice because [React state is expected to be immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

This 'awkward implementation' is also incorrect, `this.state` shouldn't be used together with `this.setState` because [`setState` is asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and may result in race conditions:

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> <...>
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

A correct way is to use updater function:

```
addItem = item => {
    this.setState(({ grudges }) => ({ grudges: [grudge, ...grudges] }));
}
```

It additionally benefits from destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is necessary because React doesn't track changes in the state like, for example, Vue. You have to explicitly tell react that the state changes. If you change state by modifying directly `this.state`, the state will be updated but the UI won't be updated since React won't know about the change.

Answer (score 1):

In react, you should only change state using setState:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html (bottom of page)